# Overlapping sections html

Tags: html, css

My two main sections of my website are overlapping and I can't seem to figure out why. I have read a lot about absolute postition etc. Maybe my whole structure is bad? I don't really know. This is my firts ever site i wrote myself. Any help would be welcome! My site can be found on: h16projecten.github.io

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: white;
}

.header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    margin: 3rem 3rem 3rem 19%;
}

.header img {
    height: 65px;
    width: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}

#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

#team {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}

.layerleft {
    position: relative;
    width: 48%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.layerright {
    width: 52%;
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-left: 420px solid white;
    border-top: 100vh solid transparent;
}

.content {
    margin: 40% -5% 2rem 40%;
    font-family: Libre Baskerville;
    font-size: 20px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-weight: 100;
    z-index: 1;
}

.media {
    margin: 1rem -3rem 2rem 40%;
    font-size: 27px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.media p ion-icon:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    color: #1c3c64;
}

#team h2 {
    font-family: Libre Baskerville;
    margin: 1rem 10rem 2rem 10%;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 1.8;
}

#team hr {
    margin: 1rem 73% 2rem 10%;
    color: #1c3c64;
    background-color: #1c3c64;
    height: 1px;
}

.teamdesc {
    margin: 4% 5rem 2rem 12%;
    font-family: Libre Baskerville;
    font-size: 30px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-weight: 100;
}

footer {
    position: relative;
    margin: 7rem 2rem 2rem 2rem;
    opacity: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.footer-desc p {
    font-family: Libre Baskerville;
    font-size: 18px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-weight: 100;
    display: inline-block;
}

.footer-logo {
    margin: 0 4% 0 0;
    height: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
}


.fullscreen-bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -100;
    height: 100%;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .content {
        margin: 110vh -90% 2rem 25%;
    }

    .media {
        margin: 1rem -3rem 2rem 25%;
    }

    .header {
        margin: 10rem 3rem 1rem 9.5%;
    }

    .layerright {
        border-left: 100px solid white;
        border-top: 100vh solid transparent;
    }

    #team h2 {
        margin: 85vh 10rem 1rem 12.5%;
    }

    #team hr {
        margin: 1rem 45% 2rem 12.5%;
    }

    .teamdesc {
        margin: 12% 5rem 2rem 14%;
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    .footer-desc p {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .footer-logo {
        height: 35px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>H16 Projecten</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.5/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='googleFonts-css'
          href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville%3A400%2C700' type='text/css' media='all'/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video loop muted autoplay playsinline class="fullscreen-bg__video">
        <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

<header class="header">
    <a class="header-logo"><img src="images/h16logobnw.png" alt="H16"></a>
</header>

<main>
    <section id="wrapper">
        <div class="layerleft">
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed hendrerit consequat elit non laoreet.
                    Pellentesque consequat sapien at tellus tempor consequat. Aliquam dictum justo a facilisis tempor.
                    Duis scelerisque congue aliquam. Sed lacinia, est in sollicitudin egestas, orci diam elementum ex,
                    ultrices posuere massa urna tincidunt massa. Mauris fermentum luctus lobortis. Morbi tempus neque a
                    justo mattis, et elementum tellus tincidunt. Vestibulum suscipit nunc at lorem lacinia lobortis.
                    Suspendisse elementum, neque vel cursus rutrum, odio lacus posuere purus, mattis hendrerit ante orci
                    porta nisl. Mauris magna tellus, faucibus ut semper.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="media">
                <p>
                    <ion-icon onclick="location.href='https://www.facebook.com/H16.projecten';"
                              name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon onclick="location.href='https://instagram.com/h16.projecten';"
                              name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="layerright">
            <!-- video -->
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="team">
        <div class="team">
            <h2>Team</h2>
            <hr>
            <div class="teamdesc">
                Name's
                <br>
                <br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi semper rhoncus odio nec luctus.
                Vestibulum
                aliquet nunc quis mi pharetra porttitor. Sed eros tortor, tincidunt ut ex ac, tincidunt tempus odio.
                Mauris
                vulputate magna et urna mollis auctor. Nam nulla.
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>

<footer class="footer">
    <img class="footer-logo" src="images/h16logobnw.png" alt="H16"> <span class="footer-desc"><p>© 2020 H16 - All right reserved</p></span>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Preview: h16projecten.github.io
Kind of like this:

[index view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c5vK.jpg)

[when scrolled down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4pXv.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What design do you want your website to have? It will be helpful if you clarify your question.

I removed the "position: absolute" from the element with the wrapper id, and it did not overlap anymore.

If you want a layout that is easy to organize and doesn't overlap, I suggest checking CSS flex. You can learn more about it in the [freeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/) website.

Comment: My begin page is as how i wantend it to be, the triangle with the video playing. When i scroll down, i want to view the ‘team’ page. A bit like m80partners.com

Comment: Then, I would style each element with `position: relative;` css, because it automatically puts every element below the other.